# Downtime when updating Ports on Kubernetes Load Balancer Service on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine

## Question

Is there a way of avoiding downtime when updating a Kubernetes LB Service's ports on GKE?

## Background

We run a platform on GKE that exposes user applications through a Load Balancer Service.

When the Service's ports are updated (add or delete), we find that HTTP and TCP connections to the Load Balancer time out for a few seconds.

If we can't avoid the disruption, we can pre-allocate a set of ports on the LB Service so that it doesn't need to be updated. Would prefer to keep the port allocation dynamic, however.

Comment: When you say "When the Service's ports are updated (add or delete)" you mean the load balancer port, or container port? The loadbalancer type creates a LoadBanlancer in GKE, are you test the application connectivity after or before the gke loadbalancer?

Comment: can you add some details about what you're doing and why?

Comment: @KoopaKiller I mean LB port, e.g. `kubectl edit service <name>`.

Comment: @PatrickW We run a platform on top of Kubernetes that allows users to deploy applications to edge/on-prem devices. We enable HTTP/TCP access to apps on those devices in a way that means their devices don't open inbound TCP/IP ports. To facilitate that, we dynamically open up ports on a Kubernetes LB Service when users create apps that need a public endpoint.

Comment: Are you using the load balancer service for that or using a mechanism to provision the lb directly?

Comment: @PatrickW Purely using the LB Service.

Comment: Well, since you are updating the resource, for me it is a expected behaviour. You can try use some layer above the service to act as a circuit breaker or similar, such as a ingress or similiar. I don't know about your worload, but maybe you can create frist another service with the desired alter and redirect the traffic for this service before update/delete the first one. What do you think?